# Retina display and css + images

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I wanted to ask, if i have some image vector, can i resize this vector x2, for example from 100x100px to 200x200px, and them apply css:

```
img.retina {width:50%;}
```

Does this image will look good in retina, or there will be no diffrence ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: By "vector" do you mean SVG? Or is your image a vector that has been converted to some bitmap format?

Comment: Smart object - which can change width, without loosing quality.

Answer (score 0):

It won't look good.
And why do you make it bigger and then just want 50% of it ?

Comment: to be as same as in layout.

Comment: i found this in web:
How to optimize bitmap images for Retina display

If you want a bitmap image that is 100px by 100px to look sharp on a Retina display, you’ll need to provide extra pixels for the Retina display to work with. This is done by making the bitmap image twice as big to begin with. (In this case we’d make the initial image 200px by 200px.) The next step involves using some programming to take the big image and scale it down to the desired 100px by 100px size.

Answer (score 0):

CSS % width is calculated based on the parent element, so you can't resize your img from 200x200 to 100x100 by writing the line width: 50%;

An alternative would be placing the img in a div.

```css
.imgContainer {
  width: 100px;
}

.imgContainer > img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgContainer">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff"/>
</div>

<p>Original Size</p>
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff"/>
```